What is the general form of the ladder operator?
It seems that ladder operators exist for nearly all operators. We have the ladder operators for the hamiltonian, for spin, and even for many particle systems where the ladder operators act as creation and annihilation operators.
Are there ladder operators for every observable? Is there a general way to determine what form the ladder operators would take?
Thank you.

You can define a ladder operator with a sum of outer products in terms of eigenstates, but ladder operators are only useful if you can obtain them another way, then use that to determine eigenstates. So the real question is which problems are efficiently solved by defining ladder operators not in terms of eigenstates.

Possible duplicate: Is it always possible to express an operator in terms of creation/annihilation operators?.

Provided that the spectrum of an operator is ordered:
$$
\hat{A}|n\rangle=a_n|n\rangle
$$
we can always construct operator
$$
b=\sum_k |k\rangle\langle k+1|,b^\dagger=\sum_k|k+1\rangle\langle k|
$$
so that
$$
b|n\rangle = |n-1\rangle,b^\dagger|n\rangle=|n-1\rangle
$$
(Some care is needed when $n$ is close to the boundaries of the spectrum - e.g., for a harmonic oscillator $n$ cannot be less than $0$, so that $b|0\rangle=0$.)
Now, we can see that $b\neq b^\dagger$, i.e., the ladder operator is not Hermitian, and as such cannot correspond to an observable quantity.

In practice we may need overall coefficients.

@J.G. Coefficients are useful, but not required. A more general approach is with Hubbard operators. One can even say that choosing the coefficients of the ladder operators is the branching point between building second quantization formalism vs. Hubbard formalism - the latter is less common in advance applications, but not impossible - e.g. Hubbard Operators in the Theory of Strongly Correlated Electrons

A ladder operator is nothing else than a shift operator with respect to the eigenvalues of another operator in the end. Roger V. explains in his answer how to construct the said ladder operator in the case of a discrete spectrum. When the latter is continuous, then it is given simply by $\hat{L} = e^{a\partial_x}$, hence $\hat{L}|x\rangle = |x+a\rangle$, where $|x\rangle$ denotes the eigenvector of an operator $\hat{X}$.
